# Tracking Clicks inside of a Div Class | Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I had a dev add a class name to a div on one of our sides and I'm attempting to track clicks to articles all inside of that div, the reader could click on the article image, title, etc. But I can't get the tag to fire.

The div class name is block-wrapper recent

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPIVP.jpg)

Here is the tag I'm using:

click element - matches CSS selector - .block-wrapper recent , .block-wrapper recent *

[tag screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT5tZ.jpg)

any help would be awesome!

Comment: Never use screenshots for code. Paste the code in the question so that we could copy it.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the css selector dealing with multiple class is not the way you tried.

```
<div class="abc xyz">
```

If you want to select it
You need to use
`div.abc.xyz`

You can see more information about css selector here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors